# I want to execute workflow when new item is inserted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio, event-receivers

```
private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        SPSite objsite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        using (SPWeb objWeb = SPContext.Current.Web)
        {
            SPList objList = objWeb.Lists["1"];

            foreach (SPListItem item in objList.Items)
            {

                if (item["xyz"] == null)
                {
                    item["xyz"] = "PLEASE SET ME!";  
                    item.Update();                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This workflow working fine but Manually.I want to execute it Automitically.Any Idea.

Answer (score 2):

You would use an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Use the Item Added or Item Updated events to execute a block of code async when an item is added in SharePoint.

Comment: This workflow is Site WorkFlow.can You Please Provide Some Code.

Comment: What is the process you do to manually execute it now?

Comment: I want to add "Please set me" to field xyz if xyz is null in list 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small, but very important addition not related directly to your question (as it was already answered by Thantos).

There is an error in your code. You should never dispose SPWeb object obtained from SPContext.Current.Web (you don't need the using operator).

Here is an article about it: [Disposing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Ya,Thanks.What is the best practice in real scenario?